# Using .hover as well as .active for css animation

Tags: css, animation

I have a div called main content, inside this div is another div called slideup. Using CSS animation, when you hover over the main content div, the slide up div slides up from the bottom to 50% height. This can be seen in my css code below

```
.maincontentdiv {
position: relative;
height: 100px;
width: 100%;
}
.slideup {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
bottom: -2px;
min-height: 0;
color: #FFF;
transition: min-height 250ms ease-in;
background-color: #666666;
text-align: center;
height:20px;
}
.maincontentdiv:active > .slideup, .maincontentdiv:hover > .slideup { 
min-height: 50%;
}
```

The hover works perfectly well, however I included the click function (.active) for touchscreen devices. I can not seem to get the click function working. Could somebody please tell me what I have done wrong?

Thanks

Comment: you surly mean `.active` and not `:active`... since it's a class the JS is adding

Comment: @vsync there is no JS it is all CSS

Comment: maybe try `.maincontentdiv:focus > .slideup`

Comment: :active only works for `mousedown` and is not a "click" function per se.

Comment: why don't you do it in JS, with a `tap` or `click` event only for touch devices, where you add/remove a class, which open/closes the menu?

Comment: @vsync how would I do this?

Comment: For an element to catch :focus CSS state, it needs the attibute tabindex="0" (value to 0 is safe). Else only form elements will catch it. so for a div : <div tabindex="0"></div> & div:focus {border:solid red} . this way it can be clicked or access via tab key

Comment: @user3760124 - you need sufficient knowledge in js for this. you must find some code which does device detection, tweak it to create a case in which it adds a class "touch" to all touch devices which do not have a mouse, and then you'll need to attach a `click` event handler to toggle a class to the element a user's touch which should change state (simulate `:hover`)

Comment: can somebody show me in context as I have no idea whether im coming or going right now haha

Comment: @GCyrillus can somebody show me in context as I have no idea whether im coming or going right now haha. So as I understand it, it is impossible to have a click event using just CSS I will have to somehow learn javascript and implement it? :)

Comment: the solution GCyrillus gave is usable when the slideup is shown just for viewing or the slideup should contain only menu, should not contain input fields, because when the slideup is shown up, focusing on the input field will hide the slideup (unfortunately that focus does not bubble up in CSS like `:hover` does). However I hope it's not the case, you can try this demo http://jsfiddle.net/CWy5G/ to see how `:focus` works.

Comment: I have eventually an example here : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/GjJtw but , what you look for should be done via javaScript even if CSS can offer some possibilities. CSS can easily break and will not be fully supported browser to browser. For a slider , the approach can be a little different and limited : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/emuiE or  a little more complex: http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/hlngD with transition. Notice that is much easier and solid to build with js support :)

Comment: @KingKing thanks but it still would not work on an ipad :( thanks anyway

Comment: @user3760124 I'm not sure why, tapping on the maincontent should focus it, then `:focus` rule should be triggered and apply the style. However there is a possibility that `tabindex` does not make your `div` become ***focusable***. As far as I know only HTML5 supports that feature. So it also depends on the browser you use (on the iPad).

Comment: @KingKing your amazing, the divs with content are working, still it appears the ones without content will not work, is this expected behaviour? some of the maincontent divs will only have a background image so thats why they don't work... any suggestions? thank thanks thanks

Comment: if you mean the `.slideup`, it obviously works on the desktop browsers even it does not contain anything. So to me it's strange to require some content for it to work on iPad.